# Is it possible to have an href attribute with data from graphql?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to make a link go to website.com/{data.from.graphql}...

Code I have right now:

```js
<a href="https://hicetnunc.xyz/objkt/{node.value.objkt_id}">{node.value.objkt_id}</a>
```

I need the link to go to [https://hicetnunc.xyz/objkt/{data}](https://hicetnunc.xyz/objkt/%7Bdata%7D) from my graphql query, is that in the realm of possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Gatsby uses JSX syntax, you'll be looking for

```
<a href={ "https://hicetnunc.xyz/objkt/" + node.value.objkt_id }>{node.value.objkt_id}</a>
```

Comment: Extending the right answer: you can also add template literals by ```<a href={`https://hicetnunc.xyz/objkt/${node.value.objkt_id}`}>{node.value.objkt_id}</a>```